# How to have autocomplete in function parameters with kwargs?

Tags: python

```
def func1(param_0, **kwargs):
    if param_0:
        return func2(**kwargs)
    else:
        return func3()

def func2(param_1 = 1, param_2 = 2):
    print("func2", param_1, param_2)

def func3():
    print("func3")
```

If I have a piece of code like this, is that possible to have parameter name autocomplete for `param_1` and `param_2` when calling `func_1`? That said, in Jupyter notebook or PyCharm or something similar, do I need to manually type in e.g. `param_1` or I could use tabs for autocompletion?

Comment: What do you mean by autocomplete?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on whatever editor or IDE you are using.

Comment: That said, what is the point of `func1`?

Comment: @chepner what will happen for the common ones (e.g., those mentioned in the question)?

Comment: @timgeb updated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get the default arguments in the call to `func2` if `func1` doesn't get them.

But be aware that of there are more arguments that `func2` doesn't have, then you will have an error.